# JAX-WS WS-RM "from java" without manually coding WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-metro-framework, ws-reliablemessaging

I have a small project publishes a web service. The wsdl is generated on the fly by the JAX-WS runtime, using annotations in my impl class.

I was hoping to simply "turn on" the Reliable Messaging aspect by flagging something. I had envisioned that I could inject some annotations in my java source and/or supplemental xml file of sorts.

Questions I have:

1) Is everything of "Metro" integrated into the JDK.

2) Does RM (Reliable Messaging) include some sort of persistent queue so that it can survive crashes and restarts without losing messages? How does the standard JDK provided JAX-WS handle this, through some sort of SQL based database storage?

3) Can I do RM without having to write WSDL files?

4) Can I use a standalone embedded Tomcat to give my application WS-RM?

5) Does anyone know of a sample that comes closest to giving an application WS-RM through an embedded Tomcat?

ps. RTFM didn't work because TFM doesn't get to the point.

Comment: It's hard and time consuming sifting around all the information on it. I'm now using a WSDL file instead, and managed to control WS-RM features through it.